# subscribe to ionic page change event

Tags: angular, ionic2

In angular2 we can subscribe to Router events as shown below:

```
router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => { /* detects route/navigation change*/
 //some logic to show loading image
});
```

How do I translate above code for use in Ionic 2?

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/ page navigation is handled by NavController in Ionic 2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want to achieve, but you can try by getting a reference of the `NavController` in the `app.components.ts` and then subscribe to the desired events like this:

```
allEvents = Observable.merge(
                 this.navController.viewDidLoad, 
                 this.navController.viewWillEnter, 
                 this.navController.viewDidEnter, 
                 this.navController.viewWillLeave, 
                 this.navController.viewDidLeave, 
                 this.navController.viewWillUnload);

allEvents.subscribe((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Please notice that in order to get the `NavController` instance in the `app.component.ts` file you'd need to do something like this:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) navCtrl: Nav;

    //...
}
```

Comment: I tried abve code. But its throwing error.                                                Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'viewDidLoad' of undefined                                                                                          Property 'viewDidLoad' does not exist on type 'Nav'.

Comment: I need  to show a loading image whenever a page is loaded. And that image should be hidden when the loading ends. I use the setroot() of Nav to load a page.